# Any risks regaring baseVault, quoteVault, baseMint Raydium v4 pool

Tags: raydium, liquiditypool, vault

How does analyzing the baseVault, quoteVault, baseMint, and related addresses in the Raydium pool help in evaluating the security against scams or rug pulls? Are there red flags in mint, freeze authorities that I should be aware of? or the supply.
I know that enabled minting and freeze authority in baseMint is a redflag but how about minting in the baseVault? i cant seem to find any documentation about it online maybe someone can give me a clearer picture of what each address is for.